# What is the nature behind the periodicity of the Mach diamonds?

Tags: flow, aerodynamics, rocket-science, propulsion, shock-waves

I've heard very interesting and sometimes contradictory hypothesis about why the [Mach Diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond) have well defined spatial periodicities. I am not sure I understand most of them, and I cannot exclude the possibility that they are just handwaved analogies.

What is the most elegant/straightforward physical explanation for this regularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of sound within the exhaust plume is not the same as it is in the ambient air outside the plume. Sonic disturbances in the plume that propagate at an angle to the flow direction refract off the impedance mismatch at the edge of the plume and bounce back and forth within the plume, creating periodic pileups.

The same sort of thing happens in river rapids, where you have a single big obstruction in the center of the river channel: a wake wave propagates out from the obstruction, bounces off the edge of the river near its bank, and travels back across the width of the river to collide in the center with the wave that similarly bounced off the opposite shore- forming a steeply peaked wave some distance behind the obstruction. This process repeats several more times, producing a periodic train of steeply peaked waves that trails behind the obstruction, with the biggest wake wave peak being the first one.